# Use torch while scanning barcode

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I'm using ZXing.Mobile.Forms to scan the barcodes.
I would like to turn the torch on while scanning the barcodes. I tried ToggleTorch() but i dont see the torch light.
Please help to overcome this scenario.
Here is my code:

```
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
        scanner.ToggleTorch();
        var option = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions { UseCode39ExtendedMode = true, TryHarder = true, PureBarcode = true, };
        var result = await scanner.Scan(option);
        if (result != null)
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, result.Text, "Cancel");
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(true);
```

Comment: Try toggle torch after scanner.Scan line.

Comment: Thanks @Vahid , it is working now but the torch is turned on only if it detect any barcode value. i would like turn the torch on while starting the scan.

Comment: Try scanner.IsTorchOn = true; before calling scanner.Scan(option);

Comment: scanner.IsTorchOn is readonly property @Vahid

Comment: Also I tried scanner.Torch(true);

Comment: Set IsTorchOn property in a binding manner, and in code-behind set this binding property to true. It's what I used and worked for me, though I'm using MVVM pattern.

Comment: @Vahid, little bit confusing. can you please share the sample code?

Answer (score 2):

OK here is the main idea which does what you want, in an MVVM manner:

**XAML:**

```
<zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="ScannerView"
                        IsTorchOn="{Binding IsTorchOn}"
                        IsScanning="{Binding IsScanning}"
                        IsAnalyzing="{Binding IsAnalyzing}"
                        ScanResultCommand="{Binding OnScanResult}"/>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class BarcodeScannerPage
    {
        private BarcodeScannerPageModel _pageModel;

        public BarcodeScannerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if(_pageModel == null) return;
            _pageModel.IsScanning = true;
            _pageModel.IsAnalyzing = true;
            _pageModel.IsTorchOn= true;
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            _pageModel = BindingContext as BarcodeScannerPageModel;
        }
    }
```

**Page model:**

```
public class BarcodeScannerPageModel
    {
        #region instance variables
        private bool _isScanning;
        private bool _isAnalyzing;
        private bool _isTorchOn;
        #endregion

        public BarcodeScannerPageModel()
        {
            IsTorchOn = true;
        }

        public bool IsScanning
        {
            get => _isScanning;
            set
            {
                _isScanning = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsAnalyzing
        {
            get => _isAnalyzing;
            set
            {
                _isAnalyzing = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand OnScanResult
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async (result) =>
                {
                        if (result.ToString().IsNullOrEmpty()) return;

                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                        {
                            IsAnalyzing = false;
                            //your code here...
                        });
                });
            }
        }

        public bool IsTorchOn
        {
            get => _isTorchOn;
            set
            {
                _isTorchOn = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I assumed MVVM is set and used correctly including "PropertyChanged" events and setting "BindingContext". More info:

[MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm)

[From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

[MVVM & Data Binding with Xamarin.Forms](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Introduction-to-MVVM)

Using some MVVM frameworks such as [FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm) can make things easier.

Comment: It is opening the scanning screen, and scans the barcode and giving me the result

Comment: xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"   is it the namespace, am i right?